# parse json using okhttp response null in onPostExecute method

Tags: android, android-asynctask, okhttp

I am developing demo for OTP. I am getting sms but problem is i am not getting response in onPostExecute method. Even response showing in logcat but my **responseString** variable always null.

my responseString Toast always null. please help me.

Here is my **AsyncTask**

```
     private class SendOTPTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {

        String responseString;


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading....");
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progressDialog.show();


        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... str) {

            MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("ContactNo", str[0]);
//            params.put("name", "your name");
            JSONObject parameter = new JSONObject(params);
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, parameter.toString());
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("http://202.131.126.46/StyleUpPlusApps.UserWebApi/api/OTP/SendOTPForRegistration")
                    .post(body)
                    .addHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
                    .build();

            client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

                    responseString = call.request().body().toString();
//                    Log.e("response error -->", call.request().body().toString());

                    new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                            .setTitle("Error")
                            .setMessage(responseString)
                            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    // continue with delete
                                }
                            })

                            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                            .show();

                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
//                    Log.e("response success -->", response.body().string());
                    responseString = response.body().string();
                    System.out.println(responseString);
                   /* if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
                    {

                        responseString = response.body().string();
                        System.out.println(responseString);
                        response.body().close();

                    }*/
                }


            });


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);

            if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + responseString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            /*if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(responseString)){

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseString);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " "+responseString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (jsonObject.getBoolean("IsSuccess")){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "OTP send...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }*/


        }

    }
```

Comment: check responseString in onResponse Method is empty or not ?

Comment: i debug my responseString have response in variable.

Comment: actually the Method onPost execute wont wait if  client.newCall(request).enqueue is gonna successfully execute or not ,so when you async starts it will call onpost execute its not gonna wait till u get Any response in onRequesr

Comment: you are returning null in doInBackground() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

> client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

is an `asynchronous` call.. which is updating responseString after some time in

> public void onResponse(Call call, Response response)

So whats happening is: `doInBackground` will call this line and exits, and `onPostExecute` will be called right after that and by this time, the asynchronous call is not excuted so **responseString** is still **null**.. Got the point?

**Suggestion**: As you are already using asynctask, so don't use the asynchronous call of okhttp, use execute() instead of enqueue(..).

Check this for more details:
https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes

Comment: so where i need to change ??

Comment: Are you following the link? What are you trying? show the code section which gives error

Comment: sorry i am new in okhttp i am replacing enqueue with execute so there is callback problem

Comment: lol.. yeah no problem.. just check the recipes link from okhttp.. it really is helpfull..

Comment: can you change in my doInBackground and add here that would be more helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132967/discussion-between-farhan-and-arpit-patel).

Answer (score -2):

That's because you are returning NULL from `doInBackground()`. Check the last line of the `doInBackground()` method and change it to return `responseString`

Comment: returning null from doInBackground has nothing to do with responseString

Comment: @Farhan Returning Null is causing onPostExecute to receive a NULL. I had a quick look at the program and missed that there is a wrapped async call. Anyways since the network call is already being made async, there is not need to be a wrapper async task.

Comment: Yes, onPostExecute will receive null but the guy is not using that.. And you are right about async thing..